# How to design Net income + Equity in an accounting system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, accounting

I'm designing an internal accounting program in Rails.

Problem: how do I design an application that calculates total Equity, including Retained Earnings + Net Income?

An example of how I'd like it to work can be seen with my Assets account.

The `Asset` model inherits from `Account` model.

It has an instance method called `balance_as_of(date)` that does exactly what you'd expect. It's implemented by looping through every Asset account's balance and adding them all together to give the *total* Asset balance.

Fair enough.

Now: the `Equity` model also inherits from the `Account` model. And therefore also has the `balance_as_of(date)` model.

The problem occurs when trying to loop through each of the `Equity` accounts. Since Net Income is a *calculated/dynamic* amount, it's not stored in the DB as an Equity account, and therefore isn't in the loop that calculates total Equity.

How can I include the dynamic calculation of Net Income as one of the accounts that the Equity loop includes?

Answer (score 0):

**Virtual Attribute**

I don't know how to calculate your "equity", but I can give you some ideas as to how you'd run this calculation in your Rails app

--

You may wish to consider the [`attr_accessor` module](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor), or perhaps just using an `instance method` to call the data.

You basically need to persist the data throughout the loop -

```
#app/models/equity.rb
Class Equity < Account
    attr_accessor :net_income

    def net_income
        self.balance_as_of([date])
    end
end
```

This will give you an attribute called `net_income` on your equity model - which will be present for each instance of the `Equity` object. For example:

```
@equities = Equity.all
@equities.each do |equity| 
   equity.net_income
end
```

It's not going to fix your problem directly, but will certainly help point you in the right direction.